# side by side chart for dimensions only in Tableau public 10

Tags: tableau-api

Hi I have data like this:
[Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jeew9.png)

I want a chart like this:
[Desired Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ikd2p.png)

Is it possible in Tableau or not? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you have to pivot the dataset columns.

To do so, in the datasource section go select the 3 columns, right click and select pivot.

You'll get 2 new fields: Pivot Field Names and Pivot Field Values.

Drag the Pivot Field Values in the dimension panel.

From the analysis Menu uncheck Aggreate measures.

Finally you shold be able to get something like this:

[image]

Comment: could you please accept the answer in order to close this thread?